# How to redirect from Identity Area to Admin in ASP.NET CORE 2

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I cant redirect from Identity Area:

```
if (role=="Admin")
                {

                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home",new { Area=Input.Role ,id=9});
                }
```

To Admin Area Controller-Home,Action-Index.Always redirect me to Index in the Identity Area;

Comment: So is the user authenticated? is the user already in the role?  what is that Input.Role? need a little more back story before we can figure what you have.. does it have be in a controller? `<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" asp-area="Admin" asp-route-id="9">Admin Area</a>`

Comment: https://github.com/vladimirpetukhov/Cake-Store-App/tree/master/CakeStore.App/Areas

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code I am still scratching my head as to the reason that someone would specify the Role at login. Can you articulate the reasoning behind this?

Simplest answer is inline with the code within the `OnPostAsync();` that resides in

```
//this because of the routes you have in StartUp.cs
[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
[Area("admin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{          

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Login.cs Page...

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {

        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");            

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User); // Claims Principle

                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
                {
                   //SIMPLEST ANSWER since you using mixed environment with PAGES
                   return LocalRedirect("~/admin");
                }

                //TODO:
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your issues below one by one:

- I got error `A method 'CakeStore.App.Areas.Admin.Controllers.HomeController.Index (CakeStore.App)' must not define attribute routed actions and non attribute routed actions at the same time`, you should not define `[HttpGet(Name ="AdminPanel")]` and `[Route(nameof(Admin) + "/[controller]")]` at the same time.

  ```
  //[HttpGet(Name ="AdminPanel")]
  [Area(nameof(Admin))]
  [Route(nameof(Admin) + "/[controller]")]
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
      return View();
  }
  ```
- For `var role = this.roleManage.GetUrl(Input.Username);`, it will retrive the role by username, check whether you got expected role `Admin`.
- `return RedirectToAction("Index","Home",new { Area=Input.Role ,id=9});`, you did not define `id` in Index, there is no need to add `id` route.